# Async Verticle vs Composite Future Verticle. How are they different?

Tags: java, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, vert.x

I have two Hello World handle methods written in Kotlin Vert.x. I want to get a clear understanding of how they are working, if possible in detail. One is AsyncVertilce while other is CompositeVerticle.

This one is Hello World Coroutine Async Verticle handle method.

```kotlin
    var result = async {
        callFunctionAwait(
            getDependentAddress(HELLO_WORLD), message.headers(), message.body(), messageMarker
        )
    }

    var result1 = async {
        callFunctionAwait(
            getDependentAddress(HELLO_WORLD), message.headers(), message.body(), messageMarker
        )
    }

    // both requests are going to execute in parallel
    val res = result.await()
    val res1 = result1.await()
    message.reply(res.body, DeliveryOptions().setHeaders(res1.headers))

}
```

This one is Hello World Coroutine Composite Verticle

```kotlin
    var future1 = callFunction(getDependentAddress(HELLO_WORLD), message.headers(), message.body(), messageMarker)
    var future2 = callFunction(getDependentAddress(HELLO_WORLD), message.headers(), message.body(), messageMarker)

    val result = CompositeFuture.all(future1, future2).await()
    if (result.succeeded()) {
        message.reply(future1.result().body, DeliveryOptions().setHeaders(future2.result().headers))
    } else {
        log.error(messageMarker, "Request failed with an exception ", result.cause())
        message.fail(500, result.cause().message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_future_coordination)

> CompositeFuture.all() takes several futures arguments (up to 6) and
> returns a future that is succeeded when all the futures are succeeded
> and failed when at least one of the futures is failed

One of the main use cases is when you want all or nothing operations; when you expect a single result for a given number of futures.

There are other variants of `CompositeFuture` like [CompositeFuture.any](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/CompositeFuture.html#any-io.vertx.core.Future-io.vertx.core.Future-) and [CompositeFuture.join](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/CompositeFuture.html#join-io.vertx.core.Future-io.vertx.core.Future-)

The `async` way of executing futures, will run each future individually and their results will be gotten irrespective of the other future(s).